# Series of equations/tikz pictures in standalone document

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, standalone, preview

I want to create a standalone document containing

a) multiple pages containing some tikz pictures(using some kind of \only command

b) some equations

c) the pages should have the size of their elements

The document is meant to serve as source for multiple bigger presentations. I have to visualize an algorithm  and want to have the equations and their corresponding tikz graphs together.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[beamer,multi,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{standaloneframe}  
\only<1>{
\begin{equation*}
1 = 2
\end{equation*}
}
\only<2->{
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt,draw] at (0,0){hi};
\only<3>{\node[draw] at (10,10){hello};

}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\end{standaloneframe}

\end{document}
```

It produces a) and b), but not c).
If I include preview, i.e.

```
 \documentclass[beamer,preview,multi,tikz]{standalone}
```

I get c) but the first equation is no longer visible. I just get the two frames for the tikz picture.

How do I fix that?

I found a work-around by including the equation as a tikz node but to do so
I have to change `equation` for `math` which doesn't produce 100% the same output in my case(it does in the example above,though)

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE. As I understand option `beamer` in `standalone` gives images, equations etc. in frames as defined in `beamer`, i.e. it not crop frames to size of its contents.

Comment: The only reason I use it  is because of the ´\only´. If there is something similar outisde of the package I would be very happy to use it.

Comment: And what gives you use `only`? With proper settings of pdf viewer (show page)  you can see only one of images from all. Or you like to have something else?

Comment: I have a big graph that I want to show in different slides with small modifications. With \only I make those modifications. This shall be basically a file containing graphs that belong together. And to these graphs do also belong certain equations. So I want to have a file containing all of them but I want the pages to be the size of the containing elements, so that they can be included in another presentation as images.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but, `tikz` option in `standalone` class draws every `tikzpicture` environment in its page. Non numbered equations can also be drawn as `tikzpicture`.

With following code, you obtain a 4 pages file. These files can be individally introduced into another document with `page` option in `\includegraphics[page=...]{...}`.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--++(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {$\cos^2 x+ \sin^2 x = 1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {$
\begin{aligned}
2^{1}&=\binom{1}{0}+\binom{1}{1}\\
2^{2}&=\binom{2}{0}+\binom{2}{1}+\binom{2}{2}
\end{aligned}
$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is -partially-what I want. The thing is that I also want to reuse parts of previous tikz pictures. Imagine the first picture is a graph and the second one is the same graph just with an edge more. Normally, I would use the \only command in the beamer class to show enable that edge on just one page, but loading beamer would turn your 4 pages into full frames, which I do not want.

Comment: So your solution and a way to reuse tikz code that doesn't destrox it would be pretty much what I want.